# ICollection / ICollection<T> ambiguity problem

Tags: c#, extension-methods, icollection, ambiguous

Just want to make simple extension for [syntactic sygar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) :

```
public static bool IsNotEmpty(this ICollection obj)
{
    return ((obj != null)
        && (obj.Count > 0));
}

public static bool IsNotEmpty<T>(this ICollection<T> obj)
{
    return ((obj != null)
        && (obj.Count > 0));
}
```

It works perfectly when I work with some collections, but when working with others I get

> The call is ambiguous between the
>   following methods or properties:
>   'PowerOn.ExtensionsBasic.IsNotEmpty(System.Collections.IList)'
>   and
>   'PowerOn.ExtensionsBasic.IsNotEmpty(System.Collections.Generic.ICollection)'

Is there any **canonical** solution to this problem ?

No, I don't want to perform a cast before calling this method ;)

Comment: Can you cite a collection that has this problem, so we can verify our answers?

Comment: Are you sure those are the declarations? The error message seems to suggest it's IList rather than ICollection.

Comment: I've run into this problem quite a bit as well, with extension methods for the generic and non-generic versions of IEnumerable, ICollection, and IList.

Comment: Is the second method even necessary?

Comment: The second method is necessary if you're dealing with types that implement ICollection<T> but not ICollection.

Comment: This is particulary needed when working with interfaces (when you do not know the concrete type of the instance you are working with) :

ICollection<T> does not implement ICollection...

Comment: @Marc Gravell: any collection that explicitly implements both interfaces has this problem. I created a new one and auto-implemented them in Visual Studio. Problem was reproduced.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: that's because `List<T>` implements both `ICollection` and `IList<T>`, while `IList<T>` inherits `ICollection<T>`. So `List<T>` implements both `ICollection` and `ICollection<T>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My best way to solve the ambiguity : define an overload for all common non-generic ICollection classes.
That means custom ICollection won't be compatible, but it's no big deal as generics are becoming the norme.

Here is the whole code :

```
/// <summary>
/// Check the given array is empty or not
/// </summary>
public static bool IsNotEmpty(this Array obj)
{
    return ((obj != null)
        && (obj.Length > 0));
}
/// <summary>
/// Check the given ArrayList is empty or not
/// </summary>
public static bool IsNotEmpty(this ArrayList obj)
{
    return ((obj != null)
        && (obj.Count > 0));
}
/// <summary>
/// Check the given BitArray is empty or not
/// </summary>
public static bool IsNotEmpty(this BitArray obj)
{
    return ((obj != null)
        && (obj.Count > 0));
}
/// <summary>
/// Check the given CollectionBase is empty or not
/// </summary>
public static bool IsNotEmpty(this CollectionBase obj)
{
    return ((obj != null)
        && (obj.Count > 0));
}
/// <summary>
/// Check the given DictionaryBase is empty or not
/// </summary>
public static bool IsNotEmpty(this DictionaryBase obj)
{
    return ((obj != null)
        && (obj.Count > 0));
}
/// <summary>
/// Check the given Hashtable is empty or not
/// </summary>
public static bool IsNotEmpty(this Hashtable obj)
{
    return ((obj != null)
        && (obj.Count > 0));
}
/// <summary>
/// Check the given Queue is empty or not
/// </summary>
public static bool IsNotEmpty(this Queue obj)
{
    return ((obj != null)
        && (obj.Count > 0));
}
/// <summary>
/// Check the given ReadOnlyCollectionBase is empty or not
/// </summary>
public static bool IsNotEmpty(this ReadOnlyCollectionBase obj)
{
    return ((obj != null)
        && (obj.Count > 0));
}
/// <summary>
/// Check the given SortedList is empty or not
/// </summary>
public static bool IsNotEmpty(this SortedList obj)
{
    return ((obj != null)
        && (obj.Count > 0));
}
/// <summary>
/// Check the given Stack is empty or not
/// </summary>
public static bool IsNotEmpty(this Stack obj)
{
    return ((obj != null)
        && (obj.Count > 0));
}
/// <summary>
/// Check the given generic is empty or not
/// </summary>
public static bool IsNotEmpty<T>(this ICollection<T> obj)
{
    return ((obj != null)
        && (obj.Count > 0));
}
```

Note that I did not want it to work on `IEnumerable<T>`, because `Count()` is a method that can trigger a database request if you are working with Linq-to-Entity or Linq-to-SQL.

Comment: After a few weeks using it, it is DEFINITELY the best solution, we mass-adopted it here.

Answer (score 4):

It's because some collections implements both interfaces, You should convert collection to concrete interface like this

```
((ICollection)myList).IsNotEmpty();
```

Or

```
((ICollection<int>)myIntList).IsNotEmpty();
```

And yea, you will get NullReferanceException if obj == null so you can remove null check ;) which mean that your extension method just compares Count whith 0 which you can do without extension method ;)

Comment: *All* of the generic versions implement their non-generic counterparts, so any generic class would have both.

Comment: Like I said in the last sentence of my question, I don't want to perform a cast before the call.

This is for SYNTACTIC SUGAR, if I need to add a cast, then it's definitely useless :p

My question remains : any way to solve ambiguity to work on all collections ?

Comment: @ArsenMkrt: extension methods can be called on variables with `value == null`, exception will not occur

Comment: @Rex M: did you mean all generic classes from .NET Framework implement non-generic interfaces? Is there any link to documentation?